# Pegando valores do array

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(6) "User01"
    ["quant"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(5) "Teste"
    ["quant"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
 [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(5) "xxXxx"
    ["quant"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

Como faço para pegar todos os campos "username" e listar, "User01, Teste, xxXxx"

Achei uma funçao que lista somente pelo id do array:

```
  $resultado[0][username];
  echo $resultado;
  User01
```

So imprimi o valor definido la[0], mas quero que imprima todos os username.

Aqui esta o code completo, mas so imprimi o ulitmo regitro.

```
$sql = 'SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS quant FROM acessos WHERE hora > :hora GROUP BY username';
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(":hora", date('H:i:s', strtotime('-1 minutes')));
$statement->execute();
$resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//var_dump($resultado);
foreach($resultado as $item){
    $dados = $item["username"];
}
 echo "-> " . $dados;
 -> xxXxx
```

Comment: Se você leu minha resposta, deve ter percebido que o `echo` tem que ficar **dentro do _loop_**.

Comment: Funcinou certo, so queria saber qual formatação pra ficar "User01, Teste, xxXxx" Obrigado pela paciencia :)

Comment: Abra outra pergunta com este problema específico, por favor. Aliás, se a resposta solucionou seu problema, você pode marcá-la usando o **✓** no lado esquerdo da resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça um *loop* pra percorrer todos os itens do array mais externo.

```
foreach($array as $item){
    echo $item["username"] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://repl.it/KgTw).